# Automatically impute zero to NA values

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace all NA values in numeric columns in my data frame with 0. How should I go about it?

I come as far as getting a list of numeric variables with NA values as follows (I am sure it is not optimal):

```
iris[3,4] <- NA
missingVars <- iris[colSums(is.na(iris)) > 0] 
missingNumVars <- missingVars[sapply(missingVars, is.numeric)]
```

Comment: Do you want to leave any NAs for non-numeric variables?

Comment: You can also do this when you read the data in if that is the origin of the data source.  Use the argument `na.strings = c(0, "NA")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will work and avoid the duplicate copies of an object of the same  size `iris` (created by `is.na(iris)`)

```
as.data.frame(lapply(iris, function(x) 
if(is.numeric(x)) {return(replace(x, is.na(x),0))} 
  else {return(x)}) )
```

Comment: I didnt follow.. Which/what duplicate is being avoided?

Comment: in `iris[is.na(iris)] <- 0` an object the size of `iris` is created as `is.na(iris)`, and in the original question `iris[colSums(is.na(iris)) > 0] `

Answer (score 9):

This should work for you

```
iris[is.na(iris)] <- 0
```